# Sources on competition policy

Tags: reference-request, competition-authority

Are there any good books or blogs on Economics in Competition Policy?

I am primarily interested in US and EU.

I know of the [Motta](https://www.cambridge.org/hu/academic/subjects/economics/industrial-economics/competition-policy-theory-and-practice?format=HB&isbn=9780521816632) and [Bishop-Walker](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Economics-Competition-Law-Application-Measurement/dp/0421931906) books but I would like something with more details on the economic methods.

E.g.:

1. more details on the econometric methods
2. more details on acquiring or cleaning data
3. more details on the industrial organization (or other) models used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently recommended '[Quantitative Techniques for Competition and Antitrust Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/9078.html)' by Peter Davis and Eliana Garcés. While it does not contain all the necessary info, it does refer to more specified books.

Answer (score 0):

The following reference could be a nice complement if you are looking for a modern micro/IO textbook presenting as non-technically as possible, the results related to imperfect competition, firms' entry and exit, concentration, pricing, etc. There is no empirical treatment, however.
Bellflamme, P. and M. Peitz, 2010, Industrial organization - markets and strategies, Cambridge University Press.
As far as I can say, few data are publicly available for confidentiality reasons, but you should have a look on the webpages of some journals making data available along with the corresponding article they publish: American Economic Review, Journal of Applied Econometrics, Journal of Business and Economic Statistics or Econometrica... for instance.

Comment: Thank you, but this is in fact the opposite of what I want: I want all the technical details. Also I don't want random bits of data, I want to learn about gathering data.

Comment: If the textbook is not technical enough you should read the published research articles which are discussed in the different chapters of the textbook. Regarding the data issue, I think that it is good think to first try reproducing descriptive statistics and empirical research performed by others, to see which data (variable scaling, etc) to use and which methods to implement. Published research often is appended by detailed description of the data.